# Cannot get Intellij to enable JPS incremental annotation processing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-212.5284.40, built on September 14, 2021` and I make heavy usage of Dagger, Lombok and a variety of other build tools and use Gradle. My build, test all work fine from Gradle (command line). In Intellij when I open my classes I can click through the Lombok builder classes fine.

But when I try to run any tests from Intellij (or build/rebuild the project) I get errors like unable to find lombok builder classes and so on. It appears to me that there is also a warning

```
java: JPS incremental annotation processing is disabled. Compilation results on partial recompilation may be inaccurate. Use build process "jps.track.ap.dependencies" VM flag to enable/disable incremental annotation processing environment.
```

I have followed the online help and added the `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` but Intellij still does not want to pick this field up (see image below). I have also tried "Invalidate and restart" and also tried increasing the heap size to be 2000MB.

[image]

Comment: You should specify `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=true` to enable incremental annotation processing. Note that this may lead to incompatible build results. See [these links](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-258659/Vertx-CodeGenProcessor-annotation-processor-is-no-longer-working-after-IDEA-upgrade#focus=Comments-27-4620217.0-0) more info about it.

Comment: I have also tried `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=true` and I get the same warning. It looks like Intellij does not want to honour that thing at all!